# Getting app data from custom uri in NDEF Record on nfc tag (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri, nfc, ndef

I have defined a custom URI scheme and added it to the App Manifest.

```
 <Extensions>
        <Protocol Name="mycustomuri" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
      </Extensions>
```

This triggers a popup "Receive Content - This will open an app associated with mycustomuri".
All okay so far, the tag and uri are playing nicely. However, appended to the URI on each tag is a unique id. The aim is, when this custom URI is detected, my app will open, navigate to 'DetectTag.xaml' and display the ID as a TextBlock.

Here is my Association Uri Mapper Class.

```
class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    private string tempUri;
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());
        // URI association launch for my app detected
        if (tempUri.Contains("mycustomuri:uid"))
        {
            // Get the category (after "Category=").
            int uidIndex = tempUri.IndexOf("uid");
            string uid = tempUri.Substring(uidIndex);
            // Redirect to the MainPage.xaml with the proper category to be displayed
            return new Uri("/DetectTag.xaml" + uid, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        // Otherwise perform normal launch.
        return uri;
    }
```

Could anyone tell me where I have gone wrong? When I tap the tag and accept the prompt, the debugger breaks - at NavigationFailed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Changed the content of the tag and the Uri Mapper.

Tag now looks like this....

```
mycustomuri:uid?uid=00001
```

UriMapper changed accordingly:

```
class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    public bool uidFound;

    private string tempUri;
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());
        // URI association launch for my app detected
        if (tempUri.Contains("mycustomuri:uid?uid="))
        {
            // Get the category (after "Category=").
            int uidIndex = tempUri.IndexOf("uid=")+7;
            string uid = tempUri.Substring(uidIndex);
            // Redirect to the MainPage.xaml with the proper category to be displayed
            return new Uri("/DetectTag.xaml?uid=" + uid, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        // Otherwise perform normal launch.
        return uri;
    }
}
```

For the sake of completion, here's the page the user is directed to.

```
public partial class DetectTag : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    int uid;
    public DetectTag()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("uid"))
        {
            uid = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["uid"]);
        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string stringUid = uid.ToString();
        tagID.Text = stringUid;

    }
}
```